# Issue with Jasmine when mocking a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a controller like below

```
(function () {

    var mockController = function ($scope, MockService) {
        $scope.message = "This is a text message";
        $scope.getCities = function () {
            return MockService.getCities();
        };

    };


    var mockService = function ($http) {
        this.getCities = function () {
            return $http.get("../rest/url", {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/yang.data+json'
                }
            });
        };
    };

    angular.module("MockApp", [])
        .service("MockService", mockService)
        .controller("MockController", mockController);

}())
```

I am trying to write a UT mocking the service like below

```
describe("MockController", function () {

    var $scope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module("MockApp");
        inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, MockService) {
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            spyOn(MockService, "getCities").and.callFake(function () {
                return [{
                    city: "Bangalore"
                    , country: "India"
                }];
            });
            controller = _$controller_("MockController", {
                $scope: $scope
            });

        });
    });

    describe("Test", function () {

        it("Should be Bangalore", function () {
            $scope.getCities()
                .then(function (data) {
                    console.log("got it");
                })
        });
    });

});
```

Its throwing an error saying

**TypeError: $scope.getCities(...).then is not a function**

Please help me.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how is Angular's $http service getting injected into your service? Also, you've created a fake for your MockService.getCitites() that's not returning a promise object. Don't think you can call the .then() function on the faked return type.

Comment: It is present in angular.js

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
$scope.getCities = function () {
  return MockService.getCities();
};
```

should be:

```
$scope.getCities = function () {
  return MockService(getCities());
};
```